# Oracle Sql How to GROUP BY with HAVING?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this simple query which works perfect in mysql, 
but when I execute it against ORACLE I'm only getting an exception.

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_NO, sum(`END` - `START`) as cnt
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
    group by EMPLOYEE_NO
    having cnt > 100;
```

Schema

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+
| EMPLOYEE_NO         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| START               | date             | NO   |     |
| END                 | date             | NO   |     |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+
```

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What error you have?

Comment: Tell us what error you get, for a start; and also show the Oracle table definition, not the MySQL one?

Answer (score 4):

Your code makes use of a MySQL extension to SQL, which Oracle does not support.  In standard SQL, a `HAVING` clause cannot reference column aliases from the `SELECT` list.  You could write your query instead as:

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE_NO, sum("END" - "START") as cnt
FROM
  EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NO
HAVING sum("END" - "START") > 100;
```

That is, repeat the expression for `cnt` in your `HAVING` clause instead of using the `SELECT` alias.

Alternatively, you could avoid repeating the expression by performing the main query as an inline view or CTE, and making the `HAVING` clause a `WHERE` clause on the parent query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      EMPLOYEE_NO, sum("END" - "START") as cnt
    FROM
      EMPLOYEES
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NO
  )
WHERE cnt > 100;
```

Additionally, you need a different identifier-quoting syntax, as shown above.

Comment: "Additionally, you need a different identifier-quoting syntax, as shown above." ... or just get rid of them entirely!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the backticks are a MySQL thing, so definitely have to remove them for Oracle.